# I got unexpected of beginning near 'nama'

Tags: mysql

```
) CREATE TABLE ahli(
    nama VARCHAR(6),
    nokp VARCHAR(12),
    id_kelas INT(2),
    tahap VARCHAR(20),
    katalaluan VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(nokp),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_kelas) REFERENCES kelas(id_kelas) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I try to change it with another words, symbol, numbers and backspace.

Comment: Show the full query and the full error message

Comment: The closing bracket should be at the end not at the beginning. How are you generating this code? And kelas must exists before you run this code segment.